# jQuery - Loaded HTML Doesn't Respond to Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, click

Here is my original code:

```
<tr class="song" id="'.$this->i.'">
   <td class="clickable" id="td1_'.$this->i.'">
   ...
   </td>
</tr>
```

And the jQuery for that:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() 
{
//
    //Make only certain parts of songs clickable
    //Hacky Way to Get Index
    var temp = $(this).attr("id");
    temp = temp.split('_');
    var i = temp[1];
    var status = $('#status_'+i).val();

    alert('Clicked ' + i);

    var maxid = $('#maxid').val();
    if(status == "max") //if maximized
    {
        alert("max");
    }
    else
    {
        var user = $("#user_min"+i).val();
        var ytcode = $("#ytcode_min"+i).val(); 
        var title = $("#title_min"+i).val(); 
        var artist = $("#artist_min"+i).val(); 
        var genre = $("#genre_min"+i).val(); 
        var score = $("#score_min"+i).val(); 
        var ups = $("#ups_min"+i).val(); 
        var downs = $("#downs_min"+i).val();
        var id = $("#id_min"+i).val(); 
        var upload_date = $("#upload_date_min+i").val(); 

        //Maximizing New Song
        dataString = 'user='+ user + '&ytcode=' + ytcode +
                         '&title=' + title + '&artist=' + artist + 
                         '&genre=' + genre + '&score=' + score + 
                         '&ups=' + ups + '&downs=' + downs + 
                         '&id=' + id + '&upload_date=' + upload_date + 
                         '&i=' + i;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "maxSongAjax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            $('#'+i).fadeIn(1000).html(html);
            }
        });

        //Setting Max ID to New Song
        $('#maxid').val(i);
    }

    return false;
});
```

I have the ajax returning identical html to what was replaced for testing purposes. However, after I click the loaded html, it does not respond to clicks. No pop-ups are shown from the alerts.

Why is this? How come the loaded html isn't responding like the first?

Comment: Post full code including your sample table. Use jsfiddle.net to help you construct the snippet. Also I see in this line --> `var upload_date = $("#upload_date_min+i").val();` the `+i` part should probably be outside the quotes, as it probably also breaking your ajax post.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the fix on upload_date. Turns out I hadn't implemented that yet so that error could not have fixed my code. 

The live solution worked great so no need to post the rest of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common issue for people new to jQuery; you have to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

.click() only binds to existing elements.

An alternative to .live() is .delegate()

Comment: It's worth noting that `.delegate()` is _significantly_ more performant than `.live()`.

Comment: If that is indeed his problem, then also, as of jQuery 1.7.0 `.live()` is deprecated in favour of `.on()`.

Comment: live() works perfectly.
on() gives me the same problem as before where only the first time it works. I made sure I have JQ 1.7. Any ideas?

Comment: if you're using .on(), try $('#table').on('click', 'td.clickable', function() { ...  This will emulate .delegate()